# Question on different definitions of upper (hemi)semicontinuity for set-valued maps

Tags: analysis, terminology, continuity

In [this thesis](http://www.math.hmc.edu/seniorthesis/archives/2008/msondjaja/msondjaja-2008-thesis.pdf)(page $8-10$), it is asserted, two definitions are equivalent, if the set-valued map $f$ maps to a compact space.

> **Definition $1$**:$f : X \to 2^Y$ is upper semicontinuous if:

1. $f(x)$ is compact for all $x \in X$, and
2. for any $x \in X$, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if
   $z \in N_{\delta}(x) \cap X$, then $f(z) \subset N_{\epsilon}(f(x))$

Here, $N_{\epsilon}(f(x))$ is a neighbourhood of “radius” $\epsilon$ of the set $f(x)$. For
any set $A$, we deﬁne a neighbourhood of radius $\epsilon$ of a set as follows:$$N_{\epsilon}(A) = \bigcup_{a \in A}N_{\epsilon}(a)$$

> **Definition $2$**:$f : X \to 2^Y$ is upper semicontinuous if: for all $x \in X$, if
>   $x$ is in the upper inverse of an open set then so is a neighbourhood of $x$.
>   An upper inverse of $E$ under a set valued map $f$ is $$f^{+}(E)=\{x \in X: f(x) \subset E\}$$

My difficulty is in how to show that definition $1$ implies definition $2$.

[image]

I can't understand in the Fourth Line, why there must exist  an $\epsilon$ such that $N_{\epsilon}(f(x)) \subset E$. Unlike definition $1$, definition $2$ doesn't require $f(x)$ is always compact. What if $f(x) = E$?

Or did I misunderstand something? It seems to me the precondition "set-valued map $f$ maps to a compact space" means $f(X)$ is compact, not that $f(x)$ is compact-valued, though I can't find  where compactness is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correspondence $\phi:[0,1]\to 2^{[0,1]}$ given by $\phi(x)=(1/3,2/3)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ is upper-hemicontinuous under Definition 2, but not under Definition 1. The proof fails if we do not also assume in Definition 2 that the correspondence is compact-valued.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A minor quesion for clarification: Does that "$f$ maps to a compact space" mean that $f(x)$ is compact-valued?

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace I would usually not read it that way, but it might well be that this is the intended meaning. But then, (1) in Definition 1 would be redundant.